# WPF Combobox Text not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been tinkering around with this one for a while and can't seem to find the problem. My styling is perfect but the combobox doesn't show the selected item in the main bar (as you can see in the image I have embedded). The dropdown list text is visible, yet it doesn't show the selected item.

My knowledge in XAML is limited so i hope someone can spot the error I've made.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#3a3a3a" />

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
                x:Name="Border"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                BorderBrush="#4a4a4a"
                BorderThickness="1" />
            <Border
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="1"
                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Path
                x:Name="Arrow"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
                Fill="White" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton
                            Name="ToggleButton"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            ClickMode="Press"
                            Focusable="false"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" />
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Name="ContentSite"
                            Margin="3,3,23,3"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        <TextBox
                            x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                            Margin="3,3,23,3"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Focusable="True"
                            IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                            Style="{x:Null}"
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                            Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <Popup
                            Name="Popup"
                            AllowsTransparency="True"
                            Focusable="False"
                            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                            Placement="Bottom"
                            PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid
                                Name="DropDown"
                                MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Border
                                    x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="1" />
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

        <ComboBox
            Name="cbxEmployees"
            Width="Auto"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="White"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"
            SelectionChanged="cbxEmployees_SelectionChanged" />
```

[Here is the empty bar once I've selected an item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7GB8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding your ContentTemplate to the template's SelectionBoxItem, like this:

```
<ContentPresenter
  Name="ContentSite"
  Margin="3,3,23,3"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  IsHitTestVisible="False"                                 
  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" />
```

The SelectionBoxItem holds the object to be shown on the Combobox. 
If you override the control's default template without binding that prop somewhere, it's gonna be lost.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed!